# Can't retrieve application rules with HNetCfg.FwMgr + AuthorizedApplications

Tags: c#, windows, firewall

I'm trying to retrieve all authorized applications with C#:

```
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
INetFwMgr firewallManager = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr"));
foreach (INetFwAuthorizedApplication app in firewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications)
{
    Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
}
```

The AuthorizedApplications is empty, but in Control Panel I can see many rules, enabled or not:

[image]

What was wrong? I tried other profiles, e.g DOMAIN/STANDARD, same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
          console.write(result);                                                            check if forEach method brings you all aplications authorized with C#                          should be a loop instead                                                                                                                                                                      
            foreach (INetFwAuthorizedApplication app in 
           firewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
            }e.g                      for(INetFwAuthorizedApplication app in  
            firewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications){console.log(app.Name);}  Are you sure Name is the correct value?, shouldn't be app.name?
```

It seems you can iterate the app list, but you are not finding the correct name for app. Use name instead Name. Try console.WriteLine(app.name) or console.WriteLine(app.GetName)

Maybe try this:

```
       public List<Object>(String name){

           ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
           INetFwMgr firewallManager = 






                           (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance 
                           (Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr"));
                           foreach (INetFwAuthorizedApplication app in 
                            firewallManager.LocalPolicy             
                           .CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications)
                         {
                          if(app.Name == _name){
                             app.Name = name;
                            Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
                               }
                                   }
                             return result;
                                }
```

Comment: It seems you can iterate the app list, but you are not finding the correct name for app. Use name instead Name. Try console.WriteLine(app.name) or console.WriteLine(app.GetName)